# Laravel sync users to all of categoires which they can be unlimited

Tags: php, laravel

In our web application each user can create multiple nested category by selecting the parent which that specified with `category_id` column.

```php
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->index()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('category_name');

    ...

    $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
    $table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent();
});
```

now you supposed one of our user created this category structure:

[image]

multiple nested categories children are unlimited, that means every category can be have child and we can't use any static or fixed number for example in `for` statement to sync the category to specify `users`.

my question is how can i set specify `users` to all of categories from parent?

this query only can set users for single child of parent. you can suppose `1`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`6`,`7` in above screen shot and not working for `2` and all of their children

children of `parent category` can be unlimited and how can we set `users` from the parent to all of nested and children categories?

```php
$category = Category::whereId($request->category_id)->whereNull('category_id')->with('childrenCategories')->first();

$category->users()->sync($request->users);
foreach ($category->childrenCategories as $category) {
    $category->users()->sync($request->users);
}
```

simplified output of query:

```
App\Entities\Category {#2114 ▼
  ...
  #attributes: array:11 [▶]
  #original: array:11 [▶]
  ...
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "childrenCategories" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2118 ▼
      #items: array:4 [▼
        0 => App\Entities\Category {#2133 ▶}
        1 => App\Entities\Category {#2134 ▶}
        2 => App\Entities\Category {#2135 ▼
          ...
          #attributes: array:11 [▶]
          #original: array:11 [▶]
          ...
          #relations: array:1 [▼
            "categories" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2138 ▼
              #items: array:1 [▼
                0 => App\Entities\Category {#2157 ▼
                  ...
                  #attributes: array:11 [▶]
                  #original: array:11 [▶]
                  ...
                  #relations: []
                  ...
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
          ...
        }
        3 => App\Entities\Category {#2136 ▶}
      ]
    }
  ]
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a recursive function like below:

```
    private function syncCategories($category,$request){

        if($category->childrenCategories->first()){
             foreach ($category->childrenCategories as $childCategory) {
                 $childCategory->users()->sync($request->users);
                 $this->syncCategories($childCategory);
              }
         }
     }
```